flask-login, flask-sqlachemy: Как из базы данных flask-sqlalchemy достать определенные данные?
Есть база данных и авторизация, произведенная на flask-login.
В БД записываются коммиты с логином, паролем и айди.
Вопрос: если произведена авторизация, то как вывести в личный кабинет именно логин и айди залогиненного пользователя?

Flask-Login. Это расширение управляет состоянием входа пользователя в систему, так что, например, пользователи могут входить в приложение, а затем переходить на разные страницы, пока приложение "запоминает", что пользователь вошел в систему. Он также предоставляет функцию "запомнить меня", которая позволяет пользователям оставаться в системе даже после закрытия окна браузера.
https://habr.com/ru/articles/808091/
